# Trouble getting the correct response in PHP to reference to Android application StringReqeust

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to get a response if the user name and password match, or don't match, so I can reference the message in my Android app and use the string to confirm it was a success and log user in. I am having trouble getting it to get the correct message. Here is my code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    require_once('connect.inc.php');

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    //avoid sql injection by setting to ?
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    //bind username and password == to username and password
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql, $fname, $lname, $username, $password, $email);

    $user = array();

    //fetch data to array of user
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
        $user['fname'] = $fname;
        $user['lname'] = $lname;
        $user['username'] = $username;
        $user['password'] = $password;
        $user['email'] = $email;
    }

    //get response if username and password match
    if(!$sql){
        echo "not connected";
    }else{
        echo "connected";
    } 

    mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

I am getting the response 'connected' no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the php documentation on mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

> `mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

So your `$sql` variable is a handle, and only returns `FALSE` if the prepare statement failed, which is why you are always seeing "connected".

If you wanted to check and see if you had a match, I would use the `num_results` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)) and check if you have one result, as that would indicate a direct match.

As a side note you shouldn't be storing your passwords in plain text. You should be hashing your passwords before storing them, and comparing the hashed passwords.

The PHP site has some [decent information on password hashing.](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Okay thank you. What I have also tried is a simple     `if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
 echo 'successfully registered';
 }else{
 'not connected ';
 }` But $sql is an object but it requires a string. Is there not a simple way to just convert it to a string?

Comment: `$sql` in this  case is the mysqli instance. `mysql_query()` is expecting a connection handle `$conn`, and a string query such as `SELECT * FROM USER`.